# error : 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, input

```
print('welcome to the marklist of the students program')
def student(dict):
    for name,marks in dict.items():
        if marks>60:
           print(f'student {name} has got a total of {marks} marks in exam and\n passed the exam with distinction ')
        elif marks>40:
            print(f'student {name} has got a total of {marks} marks in exam and\n passed the exam with first class ')
        elif marks>20:
            print(f'student {name} has got a total of {marks} marks in exam and\n passed the exam with second class ')
        else:
            print(f'student {name} has got a total of {marks} marks in exam and\n ha failed his exam ')

m={}
while True:

  a=input('enter student\'s name:')
  m=int(input('enter students marks in maths:'))
  c=int(input('enter student\'s marks in chemistry:'))
  p=int(input('enter student\'s marks in physics:'))
  cs=int(input('enter student\'s marks in computer science:'))
  t=m+c+p+cs
  m[a]=t
  b=input('want to add another students details?? enter yes or no:')
  if b=="yes":
      continue
  else:
      break

student(m)
```

so I wanted to make a program that counts the marks of students and displays the category in which student falls in but...
when I run this program it gives me a error message   
`line 22, in <module>
    m[a]=t
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment`
i don't know how to solve this problem please help....
Also this is my first question if there is any mistake with this question please tell me so i can keep correct it and do not make another mistake

Comment: You have two variables named `m`: A dict (`m={}`) and an int (`m=int(input(...))`).

Comment: Please do not save characters - had you used longer variable names you wouldn't have tripped yourself.

Comment: It is unwise to use name `dict` (and also `list`, `str` etc.) for variables.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion i will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `m` for both `dict` and also `maths` score. You can update your code to it and try this:

```
print('welcome to the marklist of the students program')
def student(dict1):
    for name,marks in dict1.items():
       if marks>60:
           print(f'student {name} has got a total of {marks} marks in exam and\n passed the exam with distinction ')
      elif marks>40:
            print(f'student {name} has got a total of {marks} marks in exam and\n passed the exam with first class ')
      elif marks>20:
           print(f'student {name} has got a total of {marks} marks in exam and\n passed the exam with second class ')
      else:
           print(f'student {name} has got a total of {marks} marks in exam and\n ha failed his exam ')

m={}
while True:

 student_name=input('enter student\'s name:')
maths_score=int(input('enter students marks in maths:'))
chemistry_score=int(input('enter student\'s marks in chemistry:'))
physics_score=int(input('enter student\'s marks in physics:'))
cs_score=int(input('enter student\'s marks in computer science:'))
t=maths_score+chemistry_score+physics_score+cs_score
m[student_name]=t
b=input('want to add another students details?? enter yes or no:')
if b=="yes":
   continue
else:
   break

student(m)
```

And also: Use `words` for defining variables

Output:

```
welcome to the marklist of the students program
enter student's name:hari
enter students marks in maths:100
enter student's marks in chemistry:100
enter student's marks in physics:100
enter student's marks in computer science:100
want to add another students details?? enter yes or no:no
student hari has got a total of 400 marks in exam and
 passed the exam with distinction
```